# keep form values after php submissions

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I am looking for a way to keep the form values after a different submit in the same code.

To keep the text after first submit, I used:

```
value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Modellocerca']) ? $_POST['Modellocerca'] : '' ?>" name="Modellocerca"
```

However, after a second submit 'Cerca' I lose the text from form.
I am really trying but I need your help guys.

```
    <html>
    <link href="Stile/TMO.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <header>
    <!-- MENU NOT RELEVANT -->
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Benvenuto.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="sottomenu">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Importa</a>
                <div class="sottomenu-content">
                    <a href="Importa.php">Sk. Reali</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Esporta</a></li>
            <li id="Logout"> <a href="Logout.php"> Logout</a> </li>
            </ul>
    </header>
    <body>      

    <!-- FIRST FORM WITH FIRST SUBMIT BUTTON --> 


    <h3>Motore di ricerca</h3>
    <form action="" method="POST"  >
        Modello: <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Modellocerca']) ? $_POST['Modellocerca'] : '' ?>"  name="Modellocerca" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cerca" Name="Cerca" />  <!-- First problem -->
    </form>

    <!-- PHP RELATED TO FIRST SUBMIT -->  
    <?php
        include('session.php');
        if(isset($_POST['Cerca']))
        {
        $Modellocerca="%";
        if ($_POST['Modellocerca'] != null) {$Modellocerca = $_POST['Modellocerca'];};
        $sql=("SELECT DISTINCT `MODELLO`, `ODM`  FROM `DBMB`.`TMO` WHERE `MODELLO` LIKE '%" . $Modellocerca . "%'");
        $sql_cerca = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sql_cerca->execute(); 
        $auxmod="start";
        foreach($db->query($sql) as $row)
            {  
            if($auxmod!=$row['MODELLO'] || $auxmod=="start") { 
                $Combomod = $Combomod . ('<option>' . $row['MODELLO'] . '</option>');
                $auxmod=$row['MODELLO'];};  
            };
        $sqlcerca=null;
        };

    ?>

    // PLOT INTO SELECT BOX THE SEARCH RESULTS AND SECOND SUBMIT FOR LOAD DATA AFTER SELECT THE RESULT  
    <form action="" method="POST" >
        <h3>Odm Filtrati</h3>
        <!-- Modello -->
        Modello: <select name="Modellocombo"> 
        <?php
            var_dump ($Combomod);
        ?> </select>
        <input  type="submit"  name="Carica" value="Carica" > <!-- Second problem -->
    </form>
```

Comment: check if the post value exists and echo it into the form directly

Comment: if you think large chunks of code are not relevent, dont include it in the post, feel free to edit and delete it. Will help people answer if you include minimum necessary

Answer (score 0):

You may use the $_SESSION variable to get input of previous form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer